# Constantly missing my calendar notifications

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, calendar, ical

For the last few months, macOS and iOS have both decided to stop actually alerting me to my meetings with an audible alarm, and I keep on missing meetings as a result. My meetings have alert times set on them, but all I get is the quiet "time sensitive" notification in the corner of my screen, and I get no sounds alerting me to the meeting.

My main computer is a MacBook Pro, and I also have an iPhone 13 and an Apple Watch connected to the same account. My meetings are kept on a Google calendar (company GSuite in particlar).

I have verified that time sensitive notifications are enabled and that all of my devices are set to notify me on calendar notifications, with sound. I have also set my phone's calendar alerts to use the old "Alert" notification.

At *most* I *might* get a quiet, subtle, easy-to-miss notification on my Apple Watch. I want my notifications to come in *everywhere*, though. This is getting ridiculous. To add insult to injury, every few days iOS prompts me once again to ask if I really want these time-sensitive notifications, which it just suddenly decides to turn off.

How can I get my devices to actually notify me of the things I want to be notified of?

Comment: Get an OS with a working calendar app, or, write your own. I'm sorry, I know that sounds like trolling, but that's the only answer for MacOS nowadays. There are many well-known, long-standing bugs they apparently just don't care about, and this is one of them. This has been a problem for years now, through many MacOS updates, and it's safe to assume that it's never going to be fixed. I missed a meeting today again because of it.